# Python string formatting inconsistent using Airflow

Tags: python, string, google-bigquery, airflow

I am using Python on Airflow to launch some BigQuery requests.

To make the script easier to read + change I made the queries as python variables, and am using python string formatting.

So I end up with the following code :

```
my_project = "my_gcp_project"
my_dataset = "my_dataset"

my_query = f"""
           SELECT * 
           FROM `{my_project}.{my_dataset}.table1`
                            
           UNION ALL 
                            
           SELECT col1,
           CAST(col2 as STRING),
           CAST(col3 as STRING)
           FROM `{my_project}.{my_dataset}.table2` 
           ORDER BY col1 DESC
"""
```

I would expect the string to end up like this :

```
print(my_query)

SELECT * 
FROM `my_project.my_dataset.table1`
                            
UNION ALL 
                            
SELECT col1,
CAST(col2 as STRING),
CAST(col3 as STRING)
FROM `my_project.my_dataset.table2` 
ORDER BY col1 DESC
```

Of course while running this on Python locally I end up with the correct result. However, when running this as an Airflow DAG, I sometimes end up with the correct result, and sometimes I end up with some weird results such as :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `my_project.table1`
                            
UNION ALL 
                            
SELECT col1,
CAST(col2 as STRING),
CAST(col3 as STRING)
FROM `my_dataset.table2` 
ORDER BY col1 DESC
```

Which ends up raising a 404 error such as

```
ERROR - 404 Not found: Dataset my_project was not found in location EU
```

I also tried using the .format() from Python, but the result is the same (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't).

Has anyone ever encoutered the same problem ?

EDIT - add DAG code

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import (
    BigQueryCheckOperator,
    BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator,
    BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator,
    BigQueryDeleteDatasetOperator,
    BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator,
    BigQueryGetDataOperator,
    BigQueryInsertJobOperator,
    BigQueryIntervalCheckOperator,
    BigQueryValueCheckOperator,
)

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
}

my_project = "my_gcp_project"
my_dataset = "my_dataset"

my_query = f"""
           SELECT * 
           FROM `{my_project}.{my_dataset}.table1`
                            
           UNION ALL 
                            
           SELECT col1,
           CAST(col2 as STRING),
           CAST(col3 as STRING)
           FROM `{my_project}.{my_dataset}.table2` 
           ORDER BY col1 DESC
"""

with DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag_id',
    default_args=args,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    tags=['tag1', 'tag2'],
) as dag:

    get_all_vouchers =  BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(
        task_id="my_task_id",
        sql=my_query,
        allow_large_results=True,
        destination_dataset_table=f"{my_project}.{my_dataset}.res",
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE"
        )
```

EDIT 2 - addition of the error logs when it occurs :

```
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2021-06-08T00:00:00+00:00
[2021-06-09 02:00:18,403] {bigquery.py:680} INFO - Executing: 
        SELECT * 
FROM `my_project.table1`

UNION ALL 

SELECT col1,
CAST(col2 as STRING),
CAST(col3 as STRING)
FROM `my_dataset.table2` 
ORDER BY col1 DESC;
        
[2021-06-09 02:00:18,424] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py:2052 DeprecationWarning: This method is deprecated. Please use `BigQueryHook.insert_job` method.
[2021-06-09 02:00:18,425] {credentials_provider.py:300} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2021-06-09 02:00:18,435] {bigquery.py:1510} INFO - Inserting job airflow_1623200418434584_6e9ba8c953365f47a7d0805a2688cd5b
[2021-06-09 02:00:18,670] {taskinstance.py:1455} ERROR - 404 Not found: Dataset my_project:my_dataset was not found in location EU
```

Comment: please post your DAG code. if my_dataset & my_project are macros i'm not clear why you are using f string.

Comment: I added the DAG code. my_dataset and my_project are not macros, they are just Python variables that I want to use in a Python string, which is my BigQuery query

Comment: I don't see how the problem you described can happen with that code (is this your real code? you hard coded the value so it can never be none as you claim). please post the log

Comment: I simplified the code for both conﬁdentiality and easy-reading purposes, but there is nothing else than BigQueryExecuteQueryOperators, with hard coded value. Which is why I don't understand why it results in a none.
I will post the log but it basically is what I described (404 ERROR, and the character as none)

Comment: Some questions:
1. How are to getting the values for those variables? Are they an Airflow variable? Just a constant?
2. Are you using jinja templating or just as you describe?

Comment: The variables are constant, there are no airflow variables. I did suspect a mess up with the jinja templating.
However after rechecking everything I think the problem is due to my the airflow setup - the code seems refreshed but when I run it, it becomes an old code (which is indeed wrong). Only part I have trouble explaining is why it happens at random but it is not a syntax problem regarding the code I shared so I think I will close the question.